# How do I perform a segue to a different view controller with a nib?

Tags: ios, swift

Currently I have successfully placed a table view nib into a view controller, but how would I perform a segue to a view controller when a cell in the nib is clicked. I have the nib in a view controller and the view controller can perform segues, but when the cell is clicked, the nib file will be performing the segue, which it can't. How do I get the segue to work? Below is the code to the nib.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.loadViewFromNib()
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "LiveConcerts", bundle: nil)
    table1.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
}
func loadViewFromNib(){
    NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("View1", owner: self, options: nil)
    print("in viewcontroller")
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arrayOfConcerts.count

}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.table1.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    let concerts = arrayOfConcerts[indexPath.row]

    cell.setCell(concerts.imageName)

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

}
```

Comment: You can perform segue from `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method

Comment: I have tried that, and ran into problems. I get the error that the nib cannot perform the segue which is expected since the row is located in the nib not the tableview, so when I call the segue, it is calling the nib not the tableview.

Comment: this is fine , your destination view controller also created by Xib or storyboard

Comment: Nib files don't *do* anything. They are simply a representation of data that is used to instantiate an object and link UIView elements to that view controller object. You can still call `performSegueWithIdentifier` as long as the current view controller came from the storyboard. Please show what you attempted and the error you received. Also, why mess around with nibs? Just put the table into the storyboard

Answer (score 1):

'For Swift 3 you can do this. You can create your segue as normal going from a table view cell to another view controller in your Storyboard.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // When selected perform our segue we set in the storyboard
    // Don't forget to set it's Storyboard Segue Identifier
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? TableViewCell
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "youSegueIdInTheStoryBoard", sender: cell)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Here we can check the segue performed above in the
    // didSelectRowAt indexPath function and 
    // Transfer any data to the destination view controller
    if (sender != nil && segue.identifier == "youSegueIdInTheStoryBoard") {
        let cell = sender as? TableViewCell
        let indexPath:IndexPath = self.tableView.indexPath(for: cell!)!
        // segue.destination is where you're now going, you can
        // cast it to whatever type it is and set things on it
    }
}
```